# JavaScript changing display using hashtag

Tags: javascript, html, css, displayobject

I'm very new to JS and have a problem with something that looks very simple.
I am trying to make a code so that if the page loads with a # at the end of the url, eg. www.example.com#hashtag, then a div will display, if it doesn't have a # the div wont display.

My Code:

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.hash) {
document.getElementById("displaydiv").style.display = "block"; 
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="displaydiv" style="display: none; height: 100px; width: 100px; 
background-color: red;"></div>
```

Comment: Make a JSFiddle of your example so its easier to help you.

Comment: Don't waste readers' time by saying that you're new to JS, stick to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is correct, but the `<script>` is executing too early, *before* the `<div>` is rendered, so I suspect you are getting a JavaScript error in the browser. Did you check the browser console?

Moving the `<script>` *after* the `<div>` will fix it but it might be wise to put the code into a function and call it after the page has loaded, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        if (window.location.hash) {
            document.getElementById("displaydiv").style.display = "block"; 
        }
    }

    window.onload = init;
</script>
```

see [Alternative to <body onload="init ();">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561315/alternative-to-body-onload-init)

Answer (score 0):

This will get the Hash (#displayDiv) and show that particular div...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var hasher = window.location.hash;

  if(hasher.indexOf('displaydiv') > -1) {
    document.getElementById("displaydiv").style.display = "block"; 
  } else if (hasher.indexOf('anotherDiv') > -1) {
    document.getElementById("anotherDiv").style.display = "block";
  }
</script>

<div id="displaydiv" style="display: none; height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple CSS solution using the [:target](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#target-pseudo) selector:

```
*:target {
  display: block;
}
```